# Does "All evil has one origin" mean "each evil has an origin" or "all the evils have the same origin"?

Tags: phrases

In "The Dagger with Wings" by G. K. Chesterton, Father Brown was talking to Mr Aylmer.

> “You mean,” observed Father Brown, “that the tragedies in your unfortunate family were not normal deaths?”
>
> “I mean they were not even normal murders,” answered the other. “The man who is hounding us all to death is a hell-hound, and his power is from hell.”
>
> “**All evil has one origin**,” said the priest gravely. “But how do you know they were not normal murders?”

Does "All evil has one origin" mean "**each evil has an origin**" or "**all the evils have the same origin**"?

Comment: Try asking this question: If you wanted to say that each evil has its own origin, how would you say it?

Comment: @IsabelArcher But I'm not sure that he want to say "each evil has its own origin", so I'm asking about the meaning of his words

Comment: It means all evils share the same origin.

Comment: I suggested you try this so that you can verify your feeling that this is not his meaning. If you can explain why you think he means "all evils have the same origin", then you will have the answer to your question.

Comment: I tend to take "each evil has an origin" because it make more sense, but I just want to make sure because Father Brown sometimes says deep philosophical meanings in his words

Comment: *One* means "the same". *An* would mean "some". *An* is an indefinite article. It stands for something indefinite. *One* is not an indefinite article. It specifies one thing.

Comment: Replace "evils" and "origin" with other nouns that are more concrete. "All these different-flavored cookies have the same basic ingredient (flour)."

Comment: While getting through a book above my reading level would be brave, Googling *All* will solve this puzzle. Checking one word is not heavy lifting. It would be doing my part before asking others. So, expecting help for *all* challenges in the same book might be considered a misunderstanding of how to get help.

Comment: The 'Each evil has a single origin as opposed to multiple origins' sense would have to use the count usage, 'All evils have one origin'. This would be ambiguous, but allows that reading. 'All evil has one origin', with the non-count usage, can only mean 'There is a single root cause of all evil/s'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means “all the evils in the world share the same origin.”

Based on the context (“his power is from hell”), it is implied that Father Brown would say that that origin is the Devil.